# Парсинг сайта с помощью python и requests и bs4

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Всем привет! получаю вот такой ответ при парсинге сайта вот фрагмент ответа

```
<movies
  :movies="[{&quot;id&quot;:9849,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;\u041b\u0451\u0434 3&quot;,&quot;age_limit&quot;:6,&quot;kp_rating&quot;:null,&quot;imdb_rating&quot;:null,&quot;duration&quot;:146,&quot;movie_link&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/cinema5.ru\/saratov\/movie\/9849_lyod-3&quot;,&quot;tag&quot;:[],&quot;trailer&quot;:{&quot;id&quot;:206934,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;trailer-led-3.mp4&quot;,&quot;disk&quot;:&quot;media_files&quot;,&quot;entity&quot;:&quot;movies&quot;,&quot;entity_file_type&quot;:&quot;trailer&quot;,&quot;entity_id&quot;:9849,&quot;status&quot;:0,&quot;size&quot;:null,&quot;path&quot;:null,&quot;external_path&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/media.cinemabox.team\/net\/c5\/movies\/9849\/trailer-led-3.mp4&quot;,&quot;media_info&quot;:null,&quot;created_at&quot;:&quot;2024-02-22T06:52:09.000000Z&quot;,&quot;updated_at&quot;:&quot;2024-02-22T06:52:09.000000Z&quot;,&quot;url&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/media.cinemabox.team\/net\/c5\/movies\/9849\/trailer-led-3.mp4&quot;,&quot;full_path&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;settings_alias&quot;:&quot;movies.trailer&quot;},&quot;genres&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:19,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;\u043c\u0435\u043b\u043e\u0434\u0440\u0430\u043c\u0430&quot;}],&quot;countries&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:165,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f&quot;}],&quot;vertical_poster_preview_src&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/cinema5.ru\/media_files\/movies\/vertical_poster_preview\/9849\/206932_65d6ef187d69b2.08787285.webp&quot;,&quot;vertical_poster_preview_src_jpg&quot;:&quot;https:\/\/cinema5.ru\/media_files\/movies\/vertical_poster_preview_jpg\/9849\/206933_65d6ef18d8aee3.65939646.jpg&quot;,&quot;shows&quot;:[{&quot;id&quot;:1669063,&quot;cinema_id&quot;:6,&quot;movie_id&quot;:9849,&quot;format&quot;:&quot;2D&quot;,&quot;time&quot;:&quot;12:00:00&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2024-03-01&quot;,&quot;max_price&quot;:270,&quot;min_price&quot;:270,&quot;hall_category_name&quot;:&quot;\u0421\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0442&quot;,&quot;pushkins_card&quot;:true},{&quot;id&quot;:1669085,&quot;cinema_id&quot;:6,&quot;movie_id&quot;:9849,&quot;format&quot;:&quot;2D&quot;,&quot;time&quot;:&quot;13:25:00&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2024-03-01&quot;,&quot;max_price&quot;:270,&quot;min_price&quot;:270,&quot;hall_category_name&quot;:&quot;\u0421\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0442&quot;,&quot;pushkins_card&quot;:true},{&quot;id&quot;:1669064,&quot;cinema_id&quot;:6,&quot;movie_id&quot;:9849,&quot;format&quot;:&quot;2D&quot;,&quot;time&quot;:&quot;14:45:00&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2024-03-01&quot;,&quot;max_price&quot;:270,&quot;min_price&quot;:270,&quot;hall_category_name&quot;:&quot;\u0421\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0442&quot;,&quot;pushkins_card&quot;:true},{&quot;id&quot;:1669065,&quot;cinema_id&quot;:6,&quot;movie_id&quot;:9849,&quot;format&quot;:&quot;2D&quot;,&quot;time&quot;:&quot;17:30:00&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2024-03-01&quot;,&quot;max_price&quot;:390,&quot;min_price&quot;:390,&quot;hall_category_name&quot;:&quot;\u0421\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0442&quot;,&quot;pushkins_card&quot;:true},{&quot;id&quot;:1669072,&quot;cinema_id&quot;:6,&quot;movie_id&quot;:9849,&quot;format&quot;:&quot;2D&quot;,&quot;time&quot;:&quot;18:40:00&quot;,&quot;date&quot;:&quot;2024-03-01&quot;,&quot;max_price&quot;:390,&quot;min_price&quot;:390,&quot;hall_category_name&quot;:&quot;\u0421\u0442\u0430\u043d\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0442&quot;,&quot;pushkins_card&quot;:true},{&quot;id&quot;:1669066,&quot;cinema_id&quot;:6,&quot;movie_id&quot;:9849,
```

не понятный для меня как с ним работать?

вот запрос:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://cinema5.ru/saratov/date/2024-03-01#/'

headers = {
                'Accept-Language': "*/*",
                "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
            }

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).text

print(response) // фрагмент ответа выше

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')

print(soup) // ответ такоже как ка в response
```

когда смотришь в google Chrome через просмотр кода то там нормальная html разметка. Как превратить ответ в html разметку? не понимаю нужно как-то декодировать или это js скрипты так отдат? Подскажите плиз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"как с ним работать?" К примерy как-то так:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

url = 'https://cinema5.ru/saratov/date/2024-03-01#/'

headers = {
    'Accept-Language': "*/*",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).text

# print(response)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')
ss = json.loads(soup.movies[':movies']) # список словарей
for s in ss:
    print(s['name'])

# Лёд 3
# Мастер и Маргарита
# ...
# Пила. Джокер
# Нечисть
```

Comment: Все понятно, спасибо! > Сергей Ш

Comment: @ВячеславЛарин чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него